# Value of type '[String]' has no member 'replacingOccurrences'?

Tags: swift

I have a problem

> Value of type `[String]` has no member `replacingOccurrences`

When I call `replacingOccurrences` it does not seem to work for Array types.

```
 func translateEquipement(equipment: [String]) -> [String]{
           var result = equipment
           let equipmentsSonoVideo = ["Lundi", "Mardi", "Mercredi", "Jeudi", "Vendredi", "Samedi", "Dimanche"]
           for equipmentSonoVideo in equipmentsSonoVideo {
               result = result.replacingOccurrences(of: equipmentSonoVideo, with: NSLocalizedString(equipmentSonoVideo, comment: "") options: NSString.CompareOptions.literal, range: nil)
           }
           return result
       }
```

My function below is for showing equipment:

```
       func showEquipments(place: Place) {
           var sonoShowed = false
           var videoShowed = false
           if let equipments = place.equipments {
               for equipment in equipments {
                   // equipement
                   if equipment == "Sono" {
                       // equipement sono
                    self.sonoLabel.text = equipment
                       sonoShowed = true
                   }
                   else if equipment == "Video projecteur" {
                       // equipement video
                    self.videoLabel.text = equipment
                       videoShowed = true
                   }
               }
           }
           if !sonoShowed {
            self.sonoContainer.isHidden = true
           }
           if !videoShowed {
            self.videoContainer.isHidden = true
           }
       }
```

Answer (score 3):

As the error says you can not use that method on an array so you need to access each string in the array individually. I did this using `map` like this

```
func translateEquipement(equipment: [String]) -> [String]{
    var result = equipment
    let equipmentsSonoVideo = ["Lundi", "Mardi", "Mercredi", "Jeudi", "Vendredi", "Samedi", "Dimanche"]
    for item in equipmentsSonoVideo {
        result = result.map {
            $0.replacingOccurrences(of: item,
                                    with: NSLocalizedString(item, comment: ""),
                                    options: NSString.CompareOptions.literal, range: nil)
        }
    }
    return result
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you like, you can create an extension for `[String]` so you can use `replacingOccurrences` as you are in your current code:

```swift
extension Array where Element == String {

    func replacingOccurrences(of target: String, with replacement: String, options: NSString.CompareOptions) -> Self
 {
        return self.map( { $0.replacingOccurrences(of: target, with: replacement, options: options) } )
    }
}
```

If you require the `NSRange` parameter that you're specifying `nil` for simply add it.